# Can a vim session use environment variables to specify the path to a file it opens?

Tags: sessions, environment-variables

Can you edit a vim session, so that it opens a file based on the value of an environment variable instead of an absolute path to a file?

Comment: With exec and edit, almost certainly. Automating it would be tough. The real question: why?

Comment: If for instance you want to edit the same files on another machine mounted at a different place.

Comment: OneDrive can cause this; sharing the files via SMB and then mounting them somewhere else.

Comment: Why the same files on another machine mounted at another place? If replicating files across systems, perhaps puppet/ansible is the right tool. Or, could use different sessions (one for each machine). Or use rsync to move files around. Or standardize the mount points. Etc.

Comment: Because I can’t.  I’m using two different windows computers with two different usernames so the “home” directory where OneDrive mounts them is different.

Comment: That’s where I made the session to begin with.  I had the files open in that directory when I saved the session.

Comment: Use symlinks (NTFS has them)? Ie. create a link with identical path on both hosts that links to the appropriate local file.

Answer (score 1):

After saving a session to a file you can edit it and replace parts of the path with the environment variables:

Original:

```
set ...
edit C:\Users\yourname\Some\Path\file.txt
set ...
```

Modified:

```
set ...
edit $HOME\Some\Path\file.txt
set ...
```